# Iterative Reduction to Null Matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, graph, matrix

Here's the problem: I'm given a matrix like

Input:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

At each step, I need to find a "second" matrix of 1's and 0's with no two 1's on the same row or column. Then, I'll subtract the second matrix from the original matrix. I will repeat the process until I get a matrix with all 0's. Furthermore, I need to take the least possible number of steps.

I need to print all the "second" matrices in O(n) time. In the above example I can get to the null matrix in 3 steps by subtracting these three matrices in order:

Expected output:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0

0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0
```

I have coded an attempt, in which I am finding the first maximum value and creating the second matrices based on the index of that value. But for the above input I am getting 4 output matrices, which is wrong:

My output:

```
1 0 0 
0 1 0 
0 0 1 

0 1 0 
1 0 0 
0 0 0 

0 0 1 
0 0 0 
1 0 0 

0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 1 0
```

My solution works for most of the test cases but fails for the one given above. Can someone give me some pointers on how to proceed, or find an algorithm that guarantees optimality?

Test case that works:

Input:

```
0 2 1
0 0 0
3 0 0
```

Output

```
0 1 0
0 0 0
1 0 0

0 1 0
0 0 0
1 0 0 

0 0 1
0 0 0
1 0 0
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? I can't really see from the examples you gave.

Comment: I am not using any algorithm...I am just getting the row/column maximum and decrementing the first non zero value.

Comment: What do you mean by the row/column maximum?

Comment: I am trying to get to all 0's in minimum number of iterations .. one row can decrement the value of one column at most and vice versa in one loop...

Comment: For example in the 3x3 matrix the row/column max is 3. to I am choosing that...

Comment: I have added a test case that works ..

Comment: I mean the the number of output matrices are noting but the maximum of row/column ... In the case that works it is 3 (row 1, row 3, col1) but in case of the first example it is also 3 but all the rows/col give 3 ... I hope it is clear

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. But I don't think that procedure is always optimal. For example, try it out on the first matrix.

Comment: Can you give an example & output of a test matrix which does not work?

Comment: Do you know of any algo which achieves this is optimal time?

Comment: My first test case with all 1's does not work ... the optimal is in 3 matrics but I am getting 4 using my procedure

Comment: Why doesn't your algorithm select the bottom-right most '1' on the second output matrix of your non-working example? Perhaps you could post your algorithm?

Comment: @threenplusone It's probably the first maximum value, not the bottom-rightmost value. The first maximum value would be value `[0][1]` since the values are all 1.

Comment: @irrelephant Ok then, perhaps taking the maximum value in a column not already selected?

Comment: yes .. I am just getting the maximum in row or column .. and then from that point I am decrementing the values in the first non zero index on that row/column. and then again recalculating the maximum row/column.

Comment: @threenplusone I'm pretty sure that the answer you just deleted is exactly the OP's algorithm. I don't see how this is always optimal; try it on `1 1 1 | 1 1 1 | 1 1 1`.

Comment: In the original problem, do you need to print out the matrices, or do you only have to find the number of matrices? And you probably mean `O(n)` instead of `o(n)`, right?

Comment: the algo @threenplusone deleted is the same as the one that i have written .. but in my first test case I successfully decrement 1 from all the three rows but next iteration, my program chooses the first non zero column which results in inoptimal solution...

Comment: @irrelephant I need to print matrices .. I can find the number of matrices which is noting but the maximum of row / column .. And it has to be O(n)

Comment: @user1459032 I posted my answer and then realised it gives the same output as yours. I have restored it now, so others may see your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Summing of each row / column and taking the largest of those sums gives you the optimal number of matrix subtractions required to reduce to a null matrix.

---

For example:

```
1 2 4 0 = 7
2 2 0 1 = 5
0 0 1 0 = 1
3 0 2 1 = 6
= = = =
6 4 7 2
```

Which means that this matrix will take 7 optimal subtractions to empty.

---

I believe that counting backwards from this and removing from columns / row with that value will solve your problem (I am not sure of an efficient way of selecting these - brute force?).
You can also use your previous method to remove extra elements.

---

For example (using the above matrix).

Step 7:
We **must** subtract from row 1 & column 3.

```
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Solves this, so now we can use your previous method to remove "bonus" elements.

```
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
```

Now apply the sum of each row / column again and continue for the next step.

Step 6:

```
1 2 3 0 = 6
1 2 0 1 = 4
0 0 1 0 = 1
3 0 2 0 = 5
= = = =
5 4 6 1
```

Next subtraction:

```
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

And so on.

---

Note: This still does not work very well with "all 1" matrices, as you get stuck on the problem of selecting 1 from every row and column (same as you did in your example).

But someone may be able to extend my solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) If all you want to do is iterate through all the elements in your matrix...

2) then all you have to do is loop `for (int i=0; i < rows*cols; i++) {}` ...

3) And such a loop is *ALREADY* O(n) (i.e. it increases LINEARLY with the #/elements in your matrix)

Comment: I think it's more complicated than that. :-)

Comment: @paulsm4 the convention when talking about matrix algorithms is than N is the number of rows or columns, not the product of the number of rows and columns. For example, matrix multiplication is O(N**3) - a 2x2 matrix takes ~2x8 operations, a 3x3 ~ 2x27 operations. So your algorithm is O(N**2). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm#Asymptotic_complexity or any other matrix algorithm description for examples of this convention.

Answer (score 0):

Let Number of rows = Number of columns = N

```
for iteration=1:N
  for row=1:N
      cell(row,(row+iteration)%N) := 0
```

Number of iterations is N. In every iteration N one's will be changed to 0

Comment: No this does not work as it decrements all the row elements to 0. i.e a[0][0], a[0][1] and a[0][2] are all decremented to 0 in the first round. The problem is when you decrement the value it has to be in a different row/column.

Comment: @user1459032 In this first round, the values decremented will be a[0][0], a[1][1], a[2][2] and so on.
If all values are 0 or 1 and number of values is N then my solution will work. I get your point if this is not the case.

Comment: I need to decrement the value by 1 each time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are after, but could you create a list of available columns and mark them as used for each iteration.

For Example:

```
repeat until an empty matrix
  mark all columns as available
  for each row
    find the maximum value in all available columns and store it's coordinates
    mark that column as unavailable
  print, decrement and clear the list of stored coordinates
```

---

This doesn't work, but it does show the algorithm that user1459032 is using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is some kind of variant of the [exact cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover_problem), which is known to be NP-complete. Your proposed algorithm is a simple greedy solution. The problem with greedy solutions is that they often work well enough to convince you that greed is good and then suddenly leave you high and dry looking for a better solution. (Consider the global economy, for example.) Anyway, Knuth's [Dancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) [Links](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0011047v1.pdf) technique is a standard way of solving the problem (exact set cover, not global economy).